# MySQL group by select row

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
+------+---------+--------+
| lang | title   | url    |
+------+---------+--------+
| pt   | Livro 1 | o294jl |
| en   | Book 1  | o294jl |
| en   | Book 2  | 7s621f |
+------+---------+--------+
```

I need to prioritize `lang` when a specific language is the system language. For example, let's say I'm working with `pt` language, I need a query that returns the following:

```
+------+---------+--------+
| lang | title   | url    |
+------+---------+--------+
| pt   | Livro 1 | o294jl |
| en   | Book 2  | 7s621f |
+------+---------+--------+
```

Basically I need to set a deterministic value for `title`, `lang`, etc when `GROUP BY url`  is being used. Currently it basically gets the lowest `id` as a value:

```
SELECT lang, title, url
FROM book
GROUP BY book.url
```

I tried using `ORDER BY` with `CASE` clauses, but as it runs after the `GROUP BY` operation, it doesn't work. I could use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `IF` to select the correct value, but since my real table has several columns, it wouldn't look ok.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `order by field()`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya he already tried that, said in the description, and also the order by which field? if you try to order it by `lang` field, the `en` also will show up first, unless you sort it as `DESC`.

Comment: Will all the language codes have a priority order? or you just want `pt` to have first priority; rest are equals and lowest row id may come ?

Comment: @AlexisVillar read up on [`field()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function

Answer (score -1):

For you case, let say if you know there's only two types of lang which 'pt' and 'en' through out your application. you may simple expend your query with `order by lang desc` .

Here's sample

```
SELECT b.lang, b.title, b.url
FROM book b
GROUP BY b.lang,b.title,b.url
ORDER BY b.lang DESC
```

But, in the event that you may have more type of lang in the future and might required to order by specific lang. i would suggest you to add one more table to hold the priority value of lang.So, you may just order by priority to get whatever lang that supposed to come first.

Here's sample

```
SELECT b.lang, b.title, b.url
FROM book b 
INNER JOIN priority p ON p.lang = b.lang
ORDER BY p.order
```

Comment: The second solution seems workable. I would remove the first solution.